# Using multipe operators in Python sequentially

Tags: python, python-3.x, operators

I'm trying to understand how Python handles using multiple sequential operators to add and subtract numbers.

Here is an example of what I mean:

```
>>> 5+-2
3
>>> 5-+2
3
>>> 5+-+-+2
7
>>> 5+-+-+-2
3
>>> 5+-+---+2
7
>>> 5-+-+---+2
3
>>> 5-+-+---+-2
7
>>> 5++++-++++--+-+++2
7
>>> 5+----2
7
>>> 5++++-2
3
>>> 5++-++-2
7
>>>
```

I don't understand what decides whether to add or subtract these two integers.
I've used Python 3.11.1 for this example.

Comment: I guess you have multiple unary `+` and unary `-` signs before the `2`.  For example, `++++++-2 = -2`,

Comment: Here's a hint: `+2` means positive 2, and `-2` means negative 2.

Comment: `5++--2` is the same as `5+(+(-(-(2))))`.

Comment: This must be a mega duplicate. What is the canonical question?

Comment: @PeterMortensen I'm sure it is, but I couldn't find the canon question so I asked it here. It turned out that the answer was very simple...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To understand how those expressions are evaluated you can use the [`ast` (abstract syntax tree) module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#module-ast).

```
>>> import ast
>>> def pretty_print_ast(code: str) -> None:
...     print(ast.dump(ast.parse(code), indent=4))
```

Now let's ask how Python evaluates `5+-2`?

```
>>> pretty_print_ast("5+-2")
    Module(
        body=[
            Expr(
                value=BinOp(
                    left=Constant(value=5),
                    op=Add(),
                    right=UnaryOp(
                        op=USub(),
                        operand=Constant(value=2))))],
        type_ignores=[])
```

So it's getting parsed as `5+(-2)`. Now let's take another example `5+-+-+2`.

```
>>> pretty_print_ast("5+-+-+2")
Module(
    body=[
        Expr(
            value=BinOp(
                left=Constant(value=5),
                op=Add(),
                right=UnaryOp(
                    op=USub(),
                    operand=UnaryOp(
                        op=UAdd(),
                        operand=UnaryOp(
                            op=USub(),
                            operand=UnaryOp(
                                op=UAdd(),
                                operand=Constant(value=2)))))))],
    type_ignores=[])
```

As you can see, it's getting parsed as `5+(-(+(-(+2))))`.

Please note that the [`UnaryOp` node in the `ast`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.UnaryOp) corresponds to the [unary operations](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#unary-arithmetic-and-bitwise-operations).

Comment: Thank you very much!  
I don't know how I didn't realized it sooner...

Answer (score 2):

I strongly recommend you to look at the concept of interpreter and stack. And you may research for programming languages concepts. This question is more of a question of how a programming language works.

Python read the line left to right. Let's assume we have a stack. Python read first value and check it's type if numeric or operator.

For example 2+-3
saved to stack

1. step we got 2 (read line until operator)
2. step: we got operator + (we and python already know if the operator is *, we should check coming char is * because ** another operator).
   Saved to stack
3. step: we got - operator. But we can not use + with another operator. So we should check if this operator shows us number is negative or positive.
   saved to stack -> -3
4. step: no coming char. So we have valid command. Otherwise we could throw exception (eg. SyntaxError)
5. step: calculate stack

This is basically how mathematical operations are done. Of course there are more of them.

Answer (score 0):

1. There is no such thing as a ++ operator in Python.
2. There is no such thing as a -- operator in Python.
3. Everything else is based on order of operations. See [Operator Precedence in Python](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence)

Comment: By --, I was mentioning a decrement operator found in other languages. In Python, two minus signs work as two prefix minus operators.